A certain distance-related map is well-defined
I am trying to understand this answer.
Context: we want to show that there exists a retract $C\to A$ where $C$ is the Cantor set and $A\subseteq C$ is a nonempty closed subset.
They suggest to take a certain distance, say
$$d((a_n), (b_n)) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{|a_n - b_n|}{3^n}$$
(if not, just take the Euclidean distance with power series with numerator 0,2 in the Cantor set and triangle inequality gives this exact formula).
It turns out that if we have three points $a,a',b$ such that $d(a,b) = d(a',b)$ then $a=a'$. Why is that?
I reckon the obvious thing to try here is to show that the distance $d(a,a')=0$. So we begin:
\begin{align}
d(a,a') = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{|a_n - a'_n|}{3^n}=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{|a_n - b_n + b_n -a'_n|}{3^n}\leq \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{|a_n - b_n|}{3^n}+\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{|a'_n - b_n|}{3^n}=2d(a,b)
\end{align}
But this seems to lead nowhere...
Another question: have we used here the Cantor set? Can we say that every closed, nonempty subset of a compact space is a retract?

We have $b=(b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots)$. Now look at the number $x=d(a,b)$, in base $3$. By construction of $d$, $x$ has ternary expansion consisting of $0$ and $1$, where each trit (ternary digit) represents the difference between $a$ and $b$ in a single position. If the $n$th trit of $x$ is $0$, then we must have $a_n=b_n$. If it is instead $1$, then $a_n=1-b_n$.
So given $b$ and $d(a,b)$, we can construct $a$, and we can only do it in one way. Therefore, if $d(a',b)=x$, we can construct $a'$ in exactly the same way, with all the same choices, and therefore we must have $a=a'$.
And yes, we have used the Cantor set, as the given space of infinite binary sequences with the given metric on it will yield the Cantor set, and nothing else. To see that it doesn't work in general, $[0,1]\cap[2,3]\subseteq [0,3]$ is not a retract (the continuous image of a connected set is connected). The fact that any nonempty closed subspace of the Cantor set is a retract speaks to how disconnected the Cantor set is.
